# Netty Server Shuts down with alive threads in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

This [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) states that the JVM doesn't stop the JAVA process if there are non-daemon threads alive in the process.

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

I've tested this with starting a standalone `Thread`, an `ExecutorService` and a `NioEventLoopGroup` and it works as stated above.

But, for this sample [Netty Echo Server](https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/echo/EchoServer.html), it states the [following](https://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/echo/EchoServer.html#81):

```
75              // Wait until the server socket is closed. 
76              f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

If I remove this line the code terminates even though there are non-daemon threads alive in the process.

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: There's no non-daemon thread alive in your example. It's just doing a graceful shutdown, and you made it less graceful. It won't stop the process from exiting.

Comment: The output of `System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount()+"," + ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getDaemonThreadCount());` is `22,4`. I printed it at the last line

Comment: Before or after `finally`? Since you're shutting things down, those threads won't stay alive. But `f.channel().closeFuture().sync()` has nothing to do with threads. It's closing a channel.

Comment: after `finally`

Comment: before, the response is `6,4`

Comment: Also, in `NioEventLoopGroup` I'm using [this](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultThreadFactory.java#L38) DefaultThreadFactory. It creates non-deamon threads.

Comment: Again, `f.channel().closeFuture().sync()` is irrelevant. It has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Then why is the program terminating? Also, since `f.channel().closeFuture().sync()` is blocking call, it stop the termination. Although it has nothing to do with it

Comment: The program is terminating because there are no live threads. Blocking on closing the channel is not thread related. Netty doesn't use blocking IO, so there's no associated thread with the channel. Even though you might see some live threads at the end, they won't be alive for long. Everything works exactly as it should.

Comment: It might be working as it should. But I'm looking for a concrete explanation on the same - what my original question was.

Comment: The concrete explanation is **there are no live threads**. If you manage print out live threads at one point, they're about to die. That's why the JVM exits. And no, even though the MXBean might tell you there are live threads, they're not going to be live for too much longer. You can pause for a second before checking the MXBean to see.

Comment: The error is in your title. You say "Netty server shuts down with alive threads in JVM". The truth is "No it doesn't, you just think there are live threads left".

Comment: That's why its a question. People ask questions because they want to correct the errors in their concepts (if any)

Comment: Well is it cleared up for you now? You've mistaken a blocking operation on a NIO channel for being related to threads, and after graceful shutdown you still see some live threads from MXBean because they haven't had a chance to exit yet. The JVM knows when there are no more live threads and exits.